# How to create a tableview having a button embedded in its one column?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to embed a button in my tablview cell.So far i have overridden the table cell and could able to reflect a button in my table view.But the problem is i want different name of button in different column.Basically the data to the table are added  dynamically.I have tried to change the cell factory dynamically but as expected it reflect the change in all cell.Any clue on this will  be appreciated .

Code:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 * @web http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/
 */
public class JavaFXDynTable extends Application {

    private TableView tableView = new TableView();
    private Button btnNew = new Button("New Record");

    static Random random = new Random();
     public static int i=0;
     private TableColumn col_action;

    static final String Day[] = {
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday"};

    public static class Record {
        private final SimpleIntegerProperty id;
        private final SimpleIntegerProperty value_0;
        private final SimpleIntegerProperty value_1;
        private final SimpleIntegerProperty value_2;
        private final SimpleIntegerProperty value_3;
        private final SimpleIntegerProperty value_4;

        Record(int i, int v0, int v1, int v2, int v3, 
                int v4) {
            this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(i);
            this.value_0 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(v0);
            this.value_1 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(v1);
            this.value_2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(v2);
            this.value_3 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(v3);
            this.value_4 = new SimpleIntegerProperty(v4);
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id.get();
        }

        public void setId(int v) {
            id.set(v);
        }

        public int getValue_0() {
            return value_0.get();
        }

        public void setValue_0(int v) {
            value_0.set(v);
        }

        public int getValue_1() {
            return value_1.get();
        }

        public void setValue_1(int v) {
            value_1.set(v);
        }

        public int getValue_2() {
            return value_2.get();
        }

        public void setValue_2(int v) {
            value_2.set(v);
        }

        public int getValue_3() {
            return value_3.get();
        }

        public void setValue_3(int v) {
            value_3.set(v);
        }

        public int getValue_4() {
            return value_4.get();
        }

        public void setValue_4(int v) {
            value_4.set(v);
        }

    };

    ObservableList<Record> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory =
                new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {

                    @Override
                    public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                        return new EditingCell();
                    }
                };

        btnNew.setOnAction(btnNewHandler);

        //init table
        //Un-editable column of "id"
        TableColumn col_id = new TableColumn("ID");
        tableView.getColumns().add(col_id);
        col_id.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<Record, String>("id"));

        //Editable columns
        for(int i=0; i<Day.length; i++){
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(Day[i]);
            col.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<Record, String>(
                            "value_" + String.valueOf(i)));
            tableView.getColumns().add(col);
            col.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        }

        //Insert Button
 col_action = new TableColumn<>("Action");
        col_action.setSortable(false);

        col_action.setCellValueFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Record, Boolean>, 
                ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Record, Boolean> p) {
                return new SimpleBooleanProperty(p.getValue() != null);
            }
        });



        col_action.setCellFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn<Record, Boolean>, TableCell<Record, Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<Record, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Record, Boolean> p) {
                return new ButtonCell("JJJJJ");
            }

        });



        tableView.getColumns().add(col_action);

        tableView.setItems(data);

        Group root = new Group();
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setSpacing(10);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(btnNew, tableView);
        root.getChildren().add(vBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    //Define the button cell
    private class ButtonCell extends TableCell<Record, Boolean> {


        private Button cellButton;

        ButtonCell(String text){
              cellButton = new Button("Action");
             cellButton.setText(text);
            cellButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                    // do something when button clicked
                    //...
                }
            });
        }

        //Display button if the row is not empty
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Boolean t, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(t, empty);
            if(!empty){
                setGraphic(cellButton);
            }
        }
    }

    EventHandler<ActionEvent> btnNewHandler = 
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {

            //generate new Record with random number
            int newId = data.size();
            if (i%2==0) {


                col_action.setCellFactory(
                        new Callback<TableColumn<Record, Boolean>, TableCell<Record, Boolean>>() {

                    @Override
                    public TableCell<Record, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Record, Boolean> p) {
                        return new ButtonCell("JJJJJ");
                    }

                });
                }
                else
                {

                    col_action.setCellFactory(
                        new Callback<TableColumn<Record, Boolean>, TableCell<Record, Boolean>>() {

                    @Override
                    public TableCell<Record, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Record, Boolean> p) {
                        return new ButtonCell("jakao");
                    }

                });



                }
                i++;
            Record newRec = new Record(
                    newId,
                    random.nextInt(100), 
                    random.nextInt(100), 
                    random.nextInt(100), 
                    random.nextInt(100), 
                    random.nextInt(100));
            data.add(newRec);

        }
    };

    class EditingCell extends TableCell<XYChart.Data, Number> {

        private TextField textField;

        public EditingCell() {}

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {

            super.startEdit();

            if (textField == null) {
                createTextField();
            }

            setGraphic(textField);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            textField.selectAll();
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();

            setText(String.valueOf(getItem()));
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(getString());
                    }
                    setGraphic(textField);
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                } else {
                    setText(getString());
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                }
            }
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()*2);
            textField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                    if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                        commitEdit(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
                    } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `ButtonCell` class you can do:

```
    ButtonCell(String text){
          cellButton = new Button();
        cellButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                // do something when button clicked
                Record record = (Record) getTableRow().getItem();
                // do something dependent on record....
            }
        });
    }
    //Display button if the row is not empty
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean t, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(t, empty);
        if(!empty){
            final Record record = (Record)getTableRow().getItem();
            cellButton.setText("Do something with "+record.getId());
            setGraphic(cellButton);
        } else { // you must always do the following in cell subclasses:
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
```

**A slightly different way to structure it:**

Instead of making your `col_action` a `TableColumn<Record, Boolean>`, you could make it a `TableColumn<Record, Record>` and do

```
col_action = new TableColumn<>("Action");
        col_action.setCellValueFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Record, Record>, 
                ObservableValue<Record>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Record, Record> p) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Record>(p.getValue());
            }
        });



        col_action.setCellFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn<Record, Record>, TableCell<Record, Record>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<Record, Record> call(TableColumn<Record, Record> p) {
                return new ButtonCell();
            }

        });
```

and then `ButtonCell` would be

```
private class ButtonCell extends TableCell<Record, Record> {


    private Button cellButton;

    ButtonCell(){
          cellButton = new Button();
        cellButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                // do something when button clicked
                Record record = getItem();
                // do something with record....
            }
        });
    }

    //Display button if the row is not empty
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Record record, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(record, empty);
        if(!empty){
            cellButton.setText("Something with "+record.getId());
            setGraphic(cellButton);
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Thanks James For the rescue .